# Practical Special Effects?

Tags: discussion

Are movie-style practical special effects questions appropriate for Arts & Crafts SE? I mean like questions about how to make realistic-looking blood, how to make a face-melting special effect, etc.

Comment: Good question. By "practical" special effects, I assume you mean actual physical implementation, as opposed to CGI or digital?

Comment: Yes, "practical" is a term of art, meaning exactly what you have deduced.

Comment: Considering that SFxMU is on topic (or has been so far) I'm not sure why this *wouldn't* be... Note that "how to make realistic blood" itself would be off topic because it's asking for a "how to"... You could certainly say "Here is my method for making blood - how can I improve the texture/color/etc"... if that makes sense.

Comment: @Catija what is SFxMU?

Comment: ... special effects makeup

Answer (score 3):

There hasn't been a definitive answer yet, so allow me.

I would say yes. There's nothing about making special effects or even props to me that would seem to be off-topic. They're specific applications of both art and craft. They would be both interesting and be answerable by experts with experience in the relevant fields.